# on-core-animated-pages-transition-end function

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I'm using two "core-animated-page" in my app
one is for page navigation and another one is inside that

i wanted to load the contents of child elements when **on-core-animated-pages-transition-end**, but its firing in both core-animated-pages

```html
<core-animated-pages id="pages" on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{loadproductsgrid}}" selected="{{route}}" valueattr="hash" transitions="slide-from-right">
    <template repeat="{{page, i in pages}}">
     <section hash="{{page.hash}}" layout="vertical center-center "> 
      </section>
        </template>
 </core-animated-pages>
```

How can i limit this to one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when that event is fired and the function is called you can check the id of the event target id to see which element sent the event

```
loadproductsgrid: function (event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'pages') {
    // will only fire if pages is the sending element 
  }
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you have a look into  this **[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498186/polymer-load-product-page-data-from-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498186/polymer-load-product-page-data-from-json)**