# Polymer Load Product Page data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

Working with an e-commerce store application with polymer
I'm loading products array using polymer `core-ajax` and using core-animated pages to display product thumbnail and product detail page (full view) but I only wanted to load the product details when clicking on each product thumb, How can I do this

Find the HTML

```html
<div id="article-content" >
<template is="auto-binding" id="page-template" >
  <core-ajax
    id="ajaxpolo" auto
    url="./json/products.json"
    handleAs="json"
    on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}" response="{{headerList}}"  on-core-response="{{postsLoaded}}">
  </core-ajax>
  <core-animated-pages id="fpages" flex selected="{{$.polo_cards.selected}}" on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{transitionend}}" transitions="cross-fade-all slide-from-right">
    <section vertical layout>
      <div id="noscroll" fit hero-p>
        <div id="container" flex horizontal wrap around-justified layout cross-fade >
          <section on-tap="{{selectView}}" id="polo_cards" >
            <template repeat="{{item in headerList}}">
              <div class="card" vertical center center-justified layout hero-id="item-{{item.id}}" hero?="{{$.polo_cards.selected === item.id || lastSelected === item.id }}" > <span cross-fade hero-transition style="">{{item.name}}</span></div>
            </template>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <template repeat="{{item in headerList}}">
      <section vertical layout>
        <div class="view" flex vertical center center-justified layout hero-id="item-{{item.id}}"    hero?="{{$.polo_cards.selected === item.id || $.polo_cards.selected === 0}}" >
          <core-icon-button class="go_back" icon="{{$.polo_cards.selected != 0 ? 'arrow-back' : 'menu'}}" on-tap="{{goback}}"></core-icon-button>
          {{item.name}} <span cross-fade class="view-cont" style="height:1000px; overflow:scroll;"></span></div>
      </section>
    </template>
  </core-animated-pages>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you would set the auto attribute of core ajax to false. `auto="false"` that would stop core-ajax from grabbing data by it's self. then set up a on-tap or on-click attribute on the element you want to be the click / tap handler. `on-tap="{{getThem}}"` then create the function.

```
getThem: function () {
  this.$.ajaxpolo.go();
}
```

that should get it. hope it helps.

edit: you will want to grab a few more things with your event.
on the click / tap handler add the id of the item you wish to get to a generic attribute. (stay away from normal attributes. ie id, title and so forth) dataId I will call it.

```
<div on-tap="{{getThem}}" dataId="{{product_id}}"></div>
```

then in your function you get a few more things with the event as i said before.

```
getThem: function (event, detail, sender) {
  var id = sender.attributes.dataId.value;
  // do something with id
}
```

i just realized i may have misunderstood when you were talking about php. sorry.

Comment: i already done something like this      
  
`template.selectView = function(e,detail,sender){
  
    this.async(function() {
        product_ajax.go();
    });`

Can you Please tell me how i send some parameters and read it in that page, without using PHP ?  i wanted to load product data based on the id

Comment: you can send post data by using the core-ajax params attribute.. you can just build out a object as normal this.postdata = {id: 100}; set it to the params attribute params="{{postdata}}". i will update answer with example

Comment: yes, but how can i read this param in the ajax page ? without php

Comment: i think i misunderstood the second part of your question. i have updated the answer. if that doesn't help let me know and i will try to help you further.